# Change the byte size of a column in SAS

Tags: sas

The default byte size of a string column is 200 bytes. So it causes a **problem:** if text is longer than 200 bytes, it's being cut.

I need to increase it to 300 with code(not with buttons). How can i do it? 
I tried changing format and informat, but that didnt affect the size.

```
format SmsText $1000.;
informat SmsText $1000.;
```

The whole code:

```
data early_dpd_for_export_cut;
    retain phoneNumber name_io url contractNumber SmsText;
    set early_dpd_for_export_cut;
    format SmsText $1000.;
    informat SmsText $1000.;
    SmsText1 = '! Не успели оплатить кредит? Перейдите по ссылке' ;
    SmsText = catx("", name_io, SmsText1);
    SmsText = catx("", SmsText, links);
    SmsText2 = 'и сообщите дату оплаты просроченной задолженности по кредитному договору. ПАО Банк "ФК Открытие". Тел. 88005007044.';   
    SmsText = catx("", SmsText, SmsText2);
    drop SmsText1;
    drop SmsText2;
run;
```

Comment: how many columns do you have in the dataset?

Comment: @SivaprasathV diffrent quantaties in each data set. Does it matter?

Comment: if the number of columns in the dataset are less you can create a dataset template with the desired sizes then add the data to that.

Comment: @SivaprasathV This is an automated process, so i need code for 'creating columns with desired size'. Can you, please, provide it?

Comment: can you add the code you tried the formats and informats in?

Comment: @SivaprasathV Done!

Comment: instead of format and informat try using length statement or attrib statement with length and format to get the desired length

Comment: Does SmSText already exist in the dataset?  If so, then the length is determined from the `set` statement.  If you want change the length of an existing variable, then put the `length` statement before `set`.

Comment: @Longfish No, all Text fileds are newly-created

Comment: I appreciate that, but the code you've posted overwrites an existing dataset.  Therefore if you ran it incorrectly once, then the new variables will exist for subsequent runs unless you remove the additional columns before each run

Comment: @Longfish I REran several previus cells to REcreate this dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Length is controlled through one of four ways:

- `Length` statement (or `attrib length`)
- `Format` statement (or `attrib format`)
- `Set` statement
- Assignment (setting the variable equal to something)

The first of those that is encountered (top to bottom, left to right) in the data step will set the length for a variable.

For a *numeric* variable, you can change the length at any time.  For a *character* variable, you cannot change the length from whatever it was the first time it is encountered in the data step.  (This is because numeric length only affects the output dataset; all numbers are 8 bytes during data step execution for speed reasons.  Character length however takes effect immediately and persists.)

As such, in order to change the length of a variable already existing on a `set` 
statement that is a character variable, you must have one of the other statements in that list (`length`, `format`, `attrib` with one of those two attributes, or assignment) prior to the `set` statement.

You can see the documentation for [length](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000218807.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
data early_dpd_for_export_cut;
    retain phoneNumber name_io url contractNumber SmsText;
    attrib length SmsText $300 format $300.;
    set early_dpd_for_export_cut;
    SmsText1 = '! Не успели оплатить кредит? Перейдите по ссылке' ;
    SmsText = catx("", name_io, SmsText1);
    SmsText = catx("", SmsText, links);
    SmsText2 = 'и сообщите дату оплаты просроченной задолженности по кредитному договору. ПАО Банк "ФК Открытие". Тел. 88005007044.';   
    SmsText = catx("", SmsText, SmsText2);
    drop SmsText1;
    drop SmsText2;
run;
```

try the length statement like this.

> the order of the length and format statements are as per the comment by [Longfish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1164962/longfish)

Comment: what happens it truncates the string still? is it removing strings or trailing and leading spaces?

Comment: Yes. The `attrib SmsText length=$300.;` didn't help either

Comment: if the trailling and leading spaces is what you want....then you shoud specify the length as $CHAR1000. if its characters then i am out of ideas...

Comment: try attrib Smstext length=$300. format=$300. ; This might help i Guess.

Comment: My guess is that SmSText already exists in the dataset (probably from the first incorrect run).  Therefore the `length` statement needs to come before `set`, otherwise it won't have any effect.

Comment: check whether the foramt and length are the same for Smstext in the datasets....it might have a larger length but if its format is less...it wont show the entire thing.

Comment: I put  `attrib Smstext length=$300. format=$300. ;` before the set statement and everything worked. **BUT** i guarantee that all the text filed are newly-created

Comment: @SivaprasathV could you please edit the answer and reference @Longfish?

Comment: reference @longfish?

Comment: @SivaprasathV yes, i followed his advice on the order of the statements was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Joe's answer is pretty complete
But from some of the comments it looks the original dataset probably also had formats attached to the character variable. That can cause the values to **appear** to be truncated.  The best thing to do is to remove `$nn.` formats from your character variables.

```
data want ;
  length make_me_longer $300 ;
  set have ;
  format _character_;
run;
```